# How to make next-auth signin routes

Tags: next-auth

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://vercel.com/guides/nextjs-prisma-postgres).

I am getting stuck at the step that asks me to make "[...nextauth].ts"

> Create a new directory and a new file in the pages/api directory:
>
> mkdir -p pages/api/auth && touch pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts
>
> Create a new directory and API route.

The link provided that explains this step leads to [this page of the documentation](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/pages). The documentation shows a director labelled [...nextauth.ts] as follows.

```
pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js
...
  pages: {
    signIn: '/auth/signin',
    signOut: '/auth/signout',
    error: '/auth/error', // Error code passed in query string as ?error=
    verifyRequest: '/auth/verify-request', // (used for check email message)
    newUser: '/auth/new-user' // New users will be directed here on first sign in (leave the property out if not of interest)
  }
...
```

I can't figure out what I am supposed to do to implement what this tutorial is asking me to do. I thought the square brackets may have been somehting that next-auth might recognise by following the command line prompt shown in the tutorial (it isn't).

I then thought maybe I'm supposed to make pages inside api/auth for each of the routes shown above (ie signIn, signOut etc). But I don't know where to put the code that is shown to belong inside [...nextauth.ts] being:

```
import { NextApiHandler } from 'next';
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import { PrismaAdapter } from '@next-auth/prisma-adapter';
import GitHubProvider from 'next-auth/providers/github';
import prisma from '../../../lib/prisma';

const authHandler: NextApiHandler = (req, res) => NextAuth(req, res, options);
export default authHandler;

const options = {
  providers: [
    GitHubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
};
```

There isn't a page for that shown in the next documentation and I can't find a way to name a file using the format shown in the documentation.

Does anyone know how to make these routes and files? What do the [... ] mean inside the file name?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is possible to make a page called [...nextauth.ts] - but for me, I have not been able to do this using the command line touch prompt as shown in the tutorial.

I don't know what the language reference for this is our how it works or why - but if you're stuck at this step, maybe the 404 is because you tried too quickly after making the oauth app